# Accessing the realm id of quickbooks online accounts for non-admin user

Tags: c#, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I'm working with the QuickBooks Online API to track user accounts, and I need to track non-admin users after the admin user has granted access. I know how to get the realm id of the admin user after the OAuth procedure, but I need to identify other users on the same company file.

Intuit's docs on https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0030_integrate_your_app/0030_signing_into_and_out_of_intuit_from_within_your_app/sign-in
say that the realmid may sometimes be available after OpenId login if it is requested, but it isn't for my case. This is what I tried for that:

```
fetch.Attributes.Add(new AttributeRequest("http://axschema.org/intuit/realmId", true));
```

I also read that it may be available through the Url referrer, but I can't find it there either :(.

How do I get the realm id of non-admin users?

**Update:**

This appears to be something completely separate from openid and oauth related to intuit's ipp platform. After the admin for the quickbooks online account grants access, you need to track account management from there, I think.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct, you need to keep track of the non-admin users.